# Jquery chosen plugin How to load remote json data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get data from a remote JSON file by using the .chosen() and .autocomplete()-plugin.
But no matter what I enter, I get "no results found". What am I doing wrong?
dont fill dropdwon rdCity
My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('f');
    $('#rdTown').change(function() {
        var globalVar
        jQuery.getJSON('@Url.Action("FillCity")', {
            id: $(this).attr('value')
        }, function(data) {
            $('#rdCity').empty();
            jQuery.each(data, function(i) {
                option = $('<option></option>').attr("value", data[i].City_id).text(data[i].Name_City);
                $('#rdCity').append(option);
                window.globalVar = (data[0].id)
                // alert(globalVar)                    
            });
        });
    });
});
```

this modal

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Town_State, ilia_Common.ilia.Fill_Town(), new { @Id = "rdTown", @class = "form-control chosen-select", style = "width:150px" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Town_State, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.City_State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
<div class="col-md-3">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.City_State, ilia_Common.ilia.Fill_City(), new { Id = "rdCity", @class = "form-control  chosen-select ", style = "width:150px" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City_State, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: so what exactly is the issue here???

Comment: dont fill dropdwon rdCity

Comment: Could you replicate the same on jsfiddle, http:\\jsfiddle.net